# Return the row number of the last non blank cell, comparing from the first row of a column until the current row, using an array formula

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've extensively searched about this and I've achieved a good level at all, but I haven't achieved my desired goal: Return the row number of the last non blank cell, having the evaluation range for the comparison starting from the first row of the desired column until the current row. This should be done using Googles' "array formula".

What I've got until now is able to perform the above task, but not using "array formula".

**My formula is as follows:**

```
=MAX(
FILTER( 
      row(
          INDIRECT(
         JOIN("";ADDRESS(1;column()+2;4);":";ADDRESS(row();column()+2;4))
                  )
          )
  ;
      INDIRECT(               
         JOIN("";ADDRESS(1;column()+2;4);":";ADDRESS(row();column()+2;4))
               )
<> "")
)
```

.

**Here goes the code sample operating over some data:**
[image]

**Summarizing, any of the following alternatives would answer my question:**

- Having my above formula converted to fit inside Google's "array formula".
- Having a new solution using "array formula".

Ps: By "arrayFormula" I mean that it just will be necessary to write the formula one time at the top of the column, allowing the array to expand to the cells bellow.

Ps2: A solution in Google AppScript would be welcomed, but I can't ensure it will completely fit the scope of my problem.

Really thanks

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).

Excel does not use FILTER or ARRAYFORMULA. Those are [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) functions. While some array fomrulas or standard functions with cyclic calculation like SUMPRODUCT or some AGGREGATE sub-functions, there is **no** formula or user defined function that fill a column with relative copies of the original formula. The Fill Handle is Excel's solution to that and simply requires double-clicking.

If you are concerned about a dynamic number of values in column A, then VBA's Worksheet_Change event sub procedure can resolve your issues.

Comment: My friend thanks for the contribuition but I've explicitly said "Having my above formula converted to fit inside Google's "array formula"." would be a solution. The "excel" tag was removed, sorry for the incovenience.